# Photoshop: how to batch combine text and existing images?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, batch-processing

In Photoshop (please don't insist on Illustrator or other software), I can use actions and create batches with variables etc. But this one is quite tricky for me.

Let's say there is an image file I need to create which will have a flag image from the root folder (e.g. USA_FLAG.PNG) and text near it that will be allocated in a Text box (e.g. "United States of America").

I can create a .txt file stating:

```
image,text
usa.png,United States of America
sweden.png,Sweden
...
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Photoshop feature that does exactly what you need.
Go Image > Variables > Define
Set variable for each layer, then import your .txt file.
Finally File > Export > Generate graphics using data sets.

See example below:
(more info [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-data-driven-graphics.html))

[image]

Comment: I was actually aware of variables which i use in creation of badges but i really did not know this doubling feature. I'm really thankful for your sincere help.

Comment: @Ahmet You are very welcome ^^